# Where can examples of advanced uses of Quill be found?

Tags: quill

The Quill documentation says:

> Users have already used [Quill] to add embedded slide decks, interactive checklists, and 3D models.

In the interest of learning Quill better, can anyone point to specific examples of these types of Quill projects on the web?